# Calculation of a voltage in a single mesh circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvwfb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why is \$v_{R_2}=(v_1-v_2)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ ?

Could anybody show me this formula, please?

\$(v_1-v_2)\$ is the voltage across \$R_1\$, which is divided between \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. I can't fully understand myself this last sentence.

**EDIT**:

I also tried to solve it this way:

The starting circuit is equivalent to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRJwLm.png)</sup>

which is equivalent to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwWd0m.png)</sup>

Thus the current on \$R_2\$ is \$(\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_2}{R_2})\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$ and the voltage \$v_{R_2}=R_2\cdot (\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_2}{R_2})\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}=v_1 \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}+ v_2 \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to skin this poor cat!

Using Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL) and Ohm's law you can write the following equation, where \$i\$ is the current in the mesh (clockwise direction):

\$
v_1 - R_1\,i - v_2 - R_2\,i = 0
\$

From this you get:

\$
i = \dfrac{v_1 - v_2}{R_1 + R_2}
\$

Apply Ohm's law to \$R_2\$ and you'll find the answer.

**EDIT**
(In response to OP editing his question)

You cannot apply equivalent circuit substitution that way. When you substitute a circuit section with an equivalent one, only the quantities **external** to that section are guaranteed to stay the same. When you substituted \$v_2/R_2\$ with its Norton equivalent, you lost track of the nodes across which you wanted to calculate the voltage (they *disappeared* inside the equivalent circuit).

If you want to go the route of Thevenin/Norton equivalence, you could substitute the series \$v_1, R_1, v_2\$ with its Thevenin equivalent: \$v_{Th}\$ (the open circuit voltage) in series with \$R_{Th}\$ (the resistance you see when you disable the voltage sources - i.e. substitute them with short circuits). You get then:

\$
v_{Th} = v_1 - v_2
\qquad 
R_{Th} = R_1
\$

Note that \$R_2\$ wasn't touched in this substitution, thus the voltage across its terminals will remain the same. Therefore now you have \$v_{Th}\$ in series with \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, so you've got a voltage divider with \$v_{Th} = v_1 - v_2\$ total applied voltage, so you get:

\$
v_{R_2} = v_{Th} \dfrac{R_2}{R_{Th} + R_2} = (v_1 - v_2) \dfrac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
\$

Comment: thank you @Lorenzo Donati. Could you check out my edit, please?

Answer (score 1):

As far as R2 is concerned, it can't tell that there are two voltage sources so, the net voltage source is V1 - V2 because they are opposing sources. This difference voltage then drives the potential divider formed by the two resistors.

Comment: Could you please draw-me an equivalent circuit to better understand it? Also: I noticed that \$v_{R_2}=v_1-v_2 - v_{R_1} = v_1 - v_2 - v_1+ v_2 =0 \$. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

$$ V_{R_2} = I × R_2  \ \ \ (1)$$

$$ I = \frac {V_T} {R_T}   \ \ \ (2)$$

Substitute (2) into (1) and rearrange.

$$ V_{R_2} = \frac {V_T} {R_T} × R_2  = {V_T}  × \frac {R_2}{R_T} \ \ \ (3)$$

It is a series circuit with two sources with opposite signs, so:

$$ R_T = R_1 + R_2 \ \ \ (4)$$
$$ V_T = V_1 - V_2 \ \ \ (5)$$

Substitute (4) and (5) into (3).

$$ V_{R_2} = {V_T}  × \frac {R_2}{R_T} = {(V_1 - V_2)}  × \frac {R_2}{(R_1 + R_2)}$$
$$ V_{R_2} = {(V_1 - V_2)}  × \frac {R_2}{(R_1 + R_2)}$$